# Half spaces free of roots of a given polynomial

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, plane-geometry

I thank Loic Teyssier and  Emil Jerabek who helped me to revise the two previous version

This  question is  motivated by the  following fact in complex variable:(I learned this fact from the book of Ahlfors, Complex Analysis)

**Fact: If all roots of a complex polynomial $p(z)$ lie in a half plane then all roots of its derivative $p'(z)$ lie in the same half plane.**

this  implies that

**If all roots  of  a  polynomial $p(z)$ is  contained in a convex set $K$ then all roots of $p'(z)$ is  contained in $K$, too.**

This  means  that The  algebra $A$ of  polynomials satisfies the following property:

**Property $P$:**

> $A$ is  an algebra of  entire functions which is  closed under derivation and for  every $f\in A$ and every convex set $K$ with $Z(f)\subseteq K $ we have $Z(f') \subseteq K$.

I have a question on this fact:

**Question:** Is there an algebra $A$ of  entire functions with the above property $P$  but  $A$ is  not equal to the  polynomial algebra?

Comment: A stronger, classical fact gives the answer to 1). If $C$ is the convex hull of the roots of $p$, then all roots of $p'$ also lie in $C$.

Comment: @LoicTeyssier Thank you very much Loic for your comment. Is not it a consequence of the initial one(about half space).According to your comment one csn replace the half plane by any arbitrary convex set.thanks again for your interesting comment.

Comment: @Loic Is there an algebra of entire functions which is closed under differentiation and satisfy the property under this post:

Comment: That is for every convex set K containing all roots of a typical f in the algebra, K must contain all roots of f'?

Comment: Every closed convex set is an intersection of half-planes, so the statements for half-planes and arbitrary convex sets are equivalent.

Comment: @Emil and Ali: yes, of course, I was too fast. Anyway, 1) is answered.

Comment: @Ali: in what sense a "typical" $f$ would be defined? Does the algebra of polynomials satisfy your property (i.e. $K$ is not fixed beforehand)?

Comment: @loic  Of course your interesting comment answered the first question.What about other algebras of entire function closed under derivation and the convex property whch we discussed?

Comment: @Emil yes as you said they are equivalent.

Comment: @Loic this is my latest question, precisly:

Comment: Assume that A is an algebra of entire function which is closed under differentiation. Moreover assume that for every f in A and every convex set K with Z(f) $\subset K$ we have Z(f') is contained in K. Does this impliy A=the algebra of polynomials?

Comment: @Loic i mean that: is there an example of this situation other than polinomial algebra?

Comment: You're right, I removed my proposal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property that the zeros of the derivative of a polynomial $P$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $P$ is usually called the Gauss-Lucas theorem.

About question 2), the algebra of entire functions of order less than 1 satisfy Property P : it is closed under derivation and satisfies the property concerning the zeros, see Corollary (3.1) p.835 in

M. Marden, On the zeros of the derivative of an entire function. 
Amer. Math. Monthly 75 1968 829–839,

or Theorem (4.2) in

M. Marden, On the derivative of an entire function. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 19 1968 1045–1051,
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1968-019-05/S0002-9939-1968-0231996-0/S0002-9939-1968-0231996-0.pdf

Comment: @use111  Thank you for  your  perfect answer.