# A Quaternions version of the Gauss Lucas theorem

Tags: polynomials, quaternions, quaternion-algebras

**Edit:** My serious thanks to Christian, Todd and Yemon  for their comments to the previous version.
The derivative is the same  as Todd says: $(az^{n})'=naz^{n-1}$.
The polynomial is in the form of $\sum a_{i}z^{i}$ not in the form of $\sum z^{i}a_{i}$,  but the comment of  Christian is  a very interesting comment

Motivated by an equivalent  formulation of the [Gauss Lucas theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242381/half-spaces-free-of-roots-of-a-given-polynomial) in terms of  half planes, we ask:

> Assume that all roots of a polynomial $p(z)$ with Quaternions coefficients is contained in  the  half space $\{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})\mid x_{4}\geq0 \}$.Is the same true  for   $p'(z)$?

Comment: These are non-commutative polynomials?  And, by the way, what is the derivative?

Comment: I assume the formal derivative where $(z^n)' = n z^{n-1}$ is meant. But it is worth remarking that noncommutative polynomials behave very differently, e.g., non-unique factorization. As for example how $z^2 + 1$ has continuum many roots.

Comment: Another issue is where to put the coefficients. Or put differently, is it clear that $\sum a_j z^j$ gives the same functions as $\sum z^j b_j$ ?

Comment: Downvoting for now, until Ali clarifies what he means by a quaternionic polynomial and its derivative

Comment: If we start with a polynomial with real coefficients, then we avoid the issue with the non-commutativity of $\sum a_j z^j $ vs. $\sum z^j a_j$, and the derivative makes sense. So perhaps there is something interesting to say here? (I think these zero sets might not lie in half-spaces of the form $x_i\geq 0$, but you could ask for arbitrary half-spaces.)